# How to send and receive ArrayList<String> using Intent?

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android. I need your help. My Problem is - I have 2 classes **Nplist.java** and **Addcustomer.java**. In my **AddCustomer** class,One `TextView` and one `Button` is there to go **Nplist** class. In my **Nplist** class there is checklist and this checklist is coming from database and all the checked values are stored in `ArrayList<String>` and one `Button` is used to go back to **AddCustomer** class. I want that `ArrayList<String>` which is in **Nplist** to by display in my **AddCustomer** class `Textview` . I haved tried these but my **Addcustomer** class crashed.

**1.Nplist.class**

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {<br>
   @Override<br>
            public void onClick(View view) {<br>
                      Bundle extra=new Bundle();<br>
                         extra.putSerializable("objects",checkedList);<br>
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Nplist.this, AddCustomer.class);<br>
                        intent.putExtra("extra",extra);<br>
                        startActivity(intent);<br>
});
```

**2.AddCustomer.class**

```
onCrete()...{
 Bundle extra = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extra");<br>
    ArrayList<String> object = (ArrayList<String>)extra.getSerializable("objects");<br>
    for (String str : object) {<br>
        getnp.append(str + "\n");<br>
}
    }
```

What do you expect the result to be? 
- What is the actual result you get? (Please include any errors.) 
When i go like this **Nplist-->AddCustomer** its working well but crash on ( **AddCustomer-->Nplist-->AddCustomer**)

Comment: Could you post the error log

Comment: may i show the code for where you initialize and assign value for a checkedList

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you are coming back to your `AddCustomer` Activity the list is null . You can solve this problem by making a global class which will store the list in a Static Field , And You can access that list from any class or Activity you want to. Try out below solution .

`Global.java` Class is as below :

```
public class Global {

    private static ArrayList<String> object = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArrayList<String> getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public static void setObject(ArrayList<String> object) {
        Global.object = object;
    }
}
```

From `NpList.java` class set the value of the list as below :

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      Global.setObject(checkedList); 
      Intent intent = new Intent(Nplist.this, AddCustomer.class);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Now Access in `AdCustomer.java` as below :

```
onCreate()...{
   Bundle extra = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extra");
   ArrayList<String> object = Global.getObject(); 
   for (String str : object) {
        getnp.append(str + "\n");
   }
}
```

This maybe helpful for you.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `putStringArrayListExtra` method you can send an array list of strings along with the intent.

Sender side:

```
Intent intent = ...
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("THE_KEY", theList);
```

Receiver side:

```
ArrayList<String> theList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("THE_KEY");
```